# Make PlotStyle aware of the number of curves that are plotted

Tags: plotting, style

I am afraid I'm having an xy-problem, so I will try to start by describing my context.

I have a function that depends on two variables, one of which I call a parameter.  I want to make a plot of the function for multiple values of the parameter, in order to visualize the smooth dependence on the parameter.  To emphasize the smoothness, I also want the plots to gradually change color, say from Red to Blue.

My (example) code is below:

```
f[x_, m_] = PDF[ NormalDistribution[ m, 1 ], x ];
blendLst[ cc_, lst_] := Blend[ cc , #] & /@ Subdivide[ 0, 1, Length@lst - 1]

ms =  Range[ 0, 10]/2;
Plot[ Evaluate[Table[ f[x, m], { m , ms}]], { x , - 4, 9}, PlotStyle -> blendLst[ {Red, Blue}, ms] ]
```

In this code, I have to make the function that blends the colors aware of the number of curves to be plotted.  In this example, this is sort of automatic, but I can imagine a situation in which the `Table` is evaluated separately.  Then I'd have to plug the number manually.  This goes against the rule to not repeat yourself and hence is error-prone.

Is there a way to define the color-blending function in a way that it'd require only the colors as arguments, but would somehow learn the total number of required colors from the context?  So my desired function `betterBlend` would work somewhat like

```
Plot[ listOfFunctions, { x , - 4, 9}, PlotStyle -> betterBlend[ {Red, Blue}] ]
```

Comment: @BobHanlon curiously, I don't evaluate the PlotStyle and still get the plot (https://imgur.com/a/avWOmFK).

Comment: Yes, I think I was confused. Disregard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[betterBlend]
Plot[a_, b_, c___, betterBlend[clrs_], d___] ^:= 
 Plot[a, b, PlotStyle -> (Blend[clrs, #1] &) /@ Subdivide[Length[a] - 1], c, d]
```

***Examples:***

```
ms =  Range[ 0, 10]/2;

f[x_, m_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[m, 1 ], x];

funcs = Table[f[x, m], {m, ms}];
```

Stick `betterBland[desiredBlendColors]` anywhere after the second argument in `Plot`:

```
Plot[funcs, {x, -4, 9}, Frame -> True, betterBlend[{Red, Blue}], Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Replace `betterBlend[{Red, Blue}]` with `betterBlend[{Red, Green, Blue}]` to get

[image]

Replace `betterBlend[{Red, Blue}]` with `betterBlend[{LightGray, Black}]` to get

[image]

Replace `betterBlend[{Red, Blue}]` with `betterBlend["Rainbow"]` to get

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[i, x], {i, ms}]], {x, 1, 10},
 betterBlend["SolarColors"], Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"SolarColors", MinMax @ ms}, ms]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is so simple and elegant.